# How to read data from txt file python

Tags: rospy, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a python script which reads data from 4 txt files and stores the values in 4 numpy arrays. I put the txt files in the same directory with my python node, but when I run the node the files cannot be located and I get the error:

> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'xdot.txt'

That works when I run the code on a python IDE, but I don't know where is the problem here. I am new to ROS and I use ROS Kinetic, Python 2.7.12 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Thank you in advance.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import rospy
import serial
import time
from std_msgs.msg import String
from decimal import Decimal
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint, solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

xdot_list = []
ydot_list = []
xdotdot_list = []
ydotdot_list = []

with open('xdot.txt', 'r') as filehandle:
    filecontents = filehandle.readlines()

    for line in filecontents:
        current_place = line[:-1]
        xdot_list.append(current_place)

xdot = np.array(xdot_list, dtype=np.float32) 

with open('ydot.txt', 'r') as filehandle:
    filecontents = filehandle.readlines()

    for line in filecontents:
        current_place = line[:-1]
        ydot_list.append(current_place)

ydot = np.array(ydot_list, dtype=np.float32) 

with open('xdotdot.txt', 'r') as filehandle:
    filecontents = filehandle.readlines()

    for line in filecontents:
        current_place = line[:-1]
        xdotdot_list.append(current_place)

xdotdot = np.array(xdotdot_list, dtype=np.float32) 

with open('ydotdot.txt', 'r') as filehandle:
    filecontents = filehandle.readlines()

    for line in filecontents:
        current_place = line[:-1]
        ydotdot_list.append(current_place)

ydotdot = np.array(ydotdot_list, dtype=np.float32)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/316614/how-to-read-data-from-txt-file-python/) by [Spyros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35598/spyros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2019-02-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I put the txt files in the same directory with my python node, but when I run the node the files cannot be located and I get the error:

> ```
> IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'xdot.txt'
> ```

> That works when I run the code on a python IDE, but I don't know where is the problem here.

The problem is in the difference in working directory when running the script directly versus using `roslaunch` or `rosrun`.

See #q235337 for more info on that.

In short: don't use relative paths, but absolute ones. To avoid hard-coding paths specific to your own PC, use ROS parameters with [substitution args](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML#substitution_args).

---

Edit:

> I checked the links you pointed out. In my occasion, it is not a problem to use an absolute path to open the file.

Absolute paths are not the problem. The problem would be to embed paths that are only valid on your own machine in your code. That is never a good idea.

> But which is the recommended way to do it in ROS applications in general?

If you want to keep things relative to package locations, you could use either something like [rospkg](http://docs.ros.org/independent/api/rospkg/html/python_api.html) or the substitution args I mentioned earlier. If you have the option, I'd go for the substitution args (as you avoid adding another dependency to your program).

---

Edit2:

> I have my 4 files in the path:  `~/catkin_ws/src/usb_rs232/scripts` in the usb_rs232 package. So the command would be:

> ```
> rosrun usb_rs232 serial_connection.py _arg_name:=$(rospack find usb_rs232)~/catkin_ws/src/usb_rs232/scripts
> ```

No.

The command would be (provided you have an actual ROS parameter in your Python script called `arg_name`):

```
rosrun usb_rs232 serial_connection.py _arg_name:=$(rospack find usb_rs232)/scripts
```

There's no need to repeat the path. `$(rospack find usb_rs232)` returns the path to `$HOME/catkin_ws/src/usb_rs232`, but without hard-coding it. The `/scripts` part would be appended to that. So in the end, `arg_name` gets the value `$HOME/catkin_ws/src/usb_rs232/scripts` assigned to it. You can then retrieve that in your script using `rospy.get_param('arg_name')` and use it as a base path, relative to which you could then open your 4 files.

---

Edit 3:

> I changed my code to:

> ```
> rospy.get_param('arg_name')
> ```

```
with open('arg_name/xdot.txt', 'r') as filehandle:
```

> with the same command and I get the error:

> ```
> KeyError: 'arg_name'
> ```

This is starting to become more of a Python question and not so much a ROS question, but: that's not how this works.

`rospy.get_param(..)` *returns* a `str` object, so you'll have to store that somewhere. Then, you should use that `str` and prefix it to the filename to get a valid path.

Something like the following should work:

```
base_dir = rospy.get_param('~arg_name')
with open(base_dir + '/xdot.txt', 'r') as filehandle:
    ...
```

Note: you only need to retrieve `arg_name` *once*. And you'll probably want to add some error checking for when the user hasn't actually set `arg_name` to a legal/proper value.

I would actually recommend to do something like this though:

```
base_dir = rospy.get_param('~arg_name')
with open(os.path.join(base_dir, 'xdot.txt'), 'r') as filehandle:
    ...
```

as that would be both more sane and portable (see [os.path.join(..)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)).

---

Edit 4:

> ```
> File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/client.py", line 465, in get_param
> ```

```
  return _param_server[param_name] #MasterProxy does all the magic for us
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/msproxy.py", line 123, in __getitem__
  raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: arg_name
```

This is basically `rospy` telling you that it cannot find the parameter.

Two things:

1. parameters set using `_name:=value` syntax of `rosrun` are [private parameters](http://wiki.ros.org/Parameter%20Server#Private_Parameters)
2. your script does not initialise a node (I don't see `rospy.init_node(..)`)

If you don't initialise a node, you cannot access private parameters (as private parameters are always private to a node: no node -> no parameters).

To retrieve a private parameter, you need to prefix the parameter name with a `~`. So `arg_name` becomes `~arg_name`.

I've also updated the code snippets in my earlier edits to show this.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-02-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Spyros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35598/spyros/) on 2019-02-26**:
Thanks for the response. I checked the links you pointed out. In my occasion, it is not a problem to use an absolute path to open the file. But which is the recommended way to do it in ROS applications in general?

**Comment by [Spyros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35598/spyros/) on 2019-02-26**:
the substitution args can be applied with `rosrun` with the same way the do with `roslaunch` ? I prefer to use rosrun but I am a bit lost in the documentation of substitution args. How can this be applied with rosrun?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-26**:
With `rosrun` it's no longer a substitution arg, as those are `roslaunch` specific.

But `rospack find` can be used on the command line, so something like this should work:

```
rosrun your_pkg your_script _arg_name:=$(rospack find pkg_with_txt_file)/path/to/file.txt
```

**Comment by [Spyros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35598/spyros/) on 2019-02-26**:
how can this work for several txt files that open in the same script? (4 in my case). The files are in the same directory.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-26**:
Pass the path to a directory instead of a file?

**Comment by [Spyros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35598/spyros/) on 2019-02-26**:
it doesn't seems to work. I have already done it with absolute path, I just wanted to know my alternatives. But it is not really convenient to type all the path every time I run the node

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-26**:\

> it doesn't seems to work.

If you can show us what "doesn't work", perhaps we can help.

> But it is not really convenient to type all the path every time I run the node

well, that is what `roslaunch` would be for.

**Comment by [Spyros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35598/spyros/) on 2019-02-26**:
I have my 4 files in the path:  `~/catkin_ws/src/usb_rs232/scripts` in the usb_rs232 package. So the command would be: `rosrun usb_rs232 serial_connection.py _arg_name:=$(rospack find usb_rs232)~/catkin_ws/src/usb_rs232/scripts` ?

**Comment by [Spyros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35598/spyros/) on 2019-02-26**:
I changed my code to:

```
rospy.get_param('arg_name')
with open('arg_name/xdot.txt', 'r') as filehandle:
```

with the same command and I get the error:

```
KeyError: 'arg_name'
```

**Comment by [Spyros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35598/spyros/) on 2019-02-27**:
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/client.py", line 465, in get_param
return _param_server[param_name] #MasterProxy does all the magic for us
File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/msproxy.py", line 123, in **getitem**
raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: arg_name

**Comment by [Spyros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35598/spyros/) on 2019-02-27**:
thanks for the patience. I still don't know what I am doing wrong here.

**Comment by [Spyros](https://answers.ros.org/users/35598/spyros/) on 2019-02-27**:
Now it works fine!I was initializing the node after the reading of the txt files. So I changed the order of my code and the node runs without errors. I will keep both methods in mind (absolute path and path set from command line) for future work. Thanks a lot for the help!!!